# Geometric series sum confusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms, computational-complexity, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Suppose I have a value k whose value is $\log_2n$ and sum of geometric series $1+2+4+8+...+2^k$ is $2^{k + 1} -1$ . Now I am calculating the complexity of a simple nested loop program and the above computation is of the inner loop. The program is below for reference.

```
class NestedLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 10; // O(time complexity of the called function)
        int sum = 0; //O(1)
        double pie = 3.14; //O(1)
        int var = 1;

    
        while(var < n) {  
            System.out.println("Pie: " + pie); 
            
            for (int j = 0; j < var; j++) {  
                sum++;  
            }
            var *= 2; 
        } //end of while loop
        
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum); //O(1)
    } //end of main
} //end of class
```

Now the inner loop condition requires that in the last time the inner loop runs, it runs at most
n times. This requires $2^k < n$ or $k < \log_2n$ . This means that the geometric series sum to $2^{\lfloor \log_2n \rfloor + 1} -1$ or $2^{\lceil \log_2n \rceil} -1$. In other words Thus, the number of iterations of the inner loop body is at least $n - 1$ and at most $2n - 3$ .

I am confused about the above conclusion. Can some one explain me in a verbose way of reaching the above statement of least and most terations of inner loop.

Comment: Operator ```sum++;``` is executed $2^{\lceil \log_2 n \rceil}-1$ times. What is $k$ in the program? Number of iterations at one inner loop pass is at least 1 (```var=1```, if $n\leq 1$ there is no way to inner loop) and at most $2^{\lceil \log_2 n \rceil-1}$ (last pass).

Comment: @Ivan ..I am confused about 2n - 3 result. I get if n is power of 2 , the iterations of inner loop will be n - 1 but how 2n - 3 is computed. I mean mathematically how we reach to that conclusion seems alien to me

Comment: Let $2^k < n \leq 2^{k+1}$, then $2^k \leq n-1$, $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil=k+1$, $2^{\lceil \log_2 n \rceil}-1=2^{k+1}-1=2\cdot 2^{k}-1 \leq 2(n-1)-1=2n-3$

Comment: @Ivan ..thats beautiful . I get it now. But how do I learn these suppositions that you have used for n in the first statement. Recommend some book please that can help me make such arguments that you just did for this problem statement .

Comment: I don't know book for this. Let we want to find upper boundary of expression $A=2^{\lceil \log_2 n \rceil}-1$ in terms of $n$ without using floor or ceiling, then we need to find upper boundary for $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil$. Let $k=\lceil \log_2 n \rceil$ (this differs from my previous comment). Then $2^{k-1} < n \leq 2^{k}$. To find upper boundary for $k$ we need to use left part of this inequality. To make it unstrict, we can use the fact that $2^{k-1}$ and $n$ are both integer, then $2^{k-1}\leq n-1$, then $A=2^{k}-1\leq 2n-3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done seems correct to me. Suppose $n$ is $k^{th}$ power of 2. Then, the outer loop runs $k$ times, which implies, inner loop runs $1+2+4+...+2^{k-1} = 2^{k}-1$ times.

Suppose n is $ 2^k + 1 $, the outer loop runs $k + 1$ times, hence the inner loop runs $2^{k+1}-1$ times. Now we can easily see that $\forall$ n $\in [2^k+1, 2^{k+1}]$, the number of times inner loop is executed is actually the same. Hence,

No of Times Inner loop executed(n) = $2^{k+1}-1$, where n $\in [2^k+1, 2^{k+1}]$, for some k $\in \mathbb{W}$

if $n = 2^{k+1}$, then No of Times Inner loop executed(n) = $2^{k+1}-1 = n-1$

if $n = 2^{k} + \alpha$, then No of Times Inner loop executed(n) = $2^{k+1}-1 = 2*(n-\alpha) - 1 = 2n - 2\alpha-1 \le 2n-3$ (least value of $\alpha$ is 1)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ..but still how we get the result of 2n - 3 from the above statement made by you. Can you elaborate on that.

Comment: You're Welcome! I have added an explanation for that in the answer